# KVM - Drive 'qed' is not whitelisted

Tags: centos7, kvm

Ok I have 2 KVM servers: server_1 and server_2.
server_1 is in production and can not talk to server_2, server_2 is in my test environment getting ready for production.

From server_1 I have copies 2 cloned VM's (I can't put the running ones off now) and moved them to server_2.

On server_2 using the gui interface I select Import existing disk image > Storage path: /home/vmpools/example.img, OS type: Linux, Version: CentOS 7.0 > RAM: 1024, CPU's 1 > Name: example and leave the rest default

Upon finish I get the following error:

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-08-18T09:29:23.423006Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=/home/vmpools/SureCollectGateway.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qed: could not open disk image /home/vmpools/SureCollectGateway.img: Driver 'qed' is not whitelisted
'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 90, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2277, in _do_async_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 501, in start_install
    noboot)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 416, in _create_guest
    dom = self.conn.createLinux(start_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3606, in createLinux
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateLinux() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-08-18T09:29:23.423006Z qemu-kvm: -drive file=/home/vmpools/SureCollectGateway.img,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=qed: could not open disk image /home/vmpools/SureCollectGateway.img: Driver 'qed' is not whitelisted
```

However I can create new VM's from ISO's.

How would I go about white listing qed or what am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

CentOS dose not supprt the `qed` disk format, use `qcow2` instead.

1. https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=8986
2. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.0_Release_Notes/Known-Issues-Virtualization.html

> qemu-kvm component, BZ#731570
>       The QEMU Enhanced Disk format (QED) for KVM guest virtual machines is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7. Use the qcow2 image
>   format instead.